# HttpContext Response is not writing when called in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, httpresponse

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC site and I am trying to enable a file download. The user selects some data and it gets added to a comma separated string that will convert to a csv file. I have all the data needed for the file, but when I call HttpContext.Current.Response, nothing is happening. This feature was working previously, but now for some reason I can't get the response to do anything.

This is the code (that once worked):

```
            var response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.BufferOutput = true;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FN + ".csv");
            response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            response.Write(sb.ToString());
            response.End();
```

This code is executed once the user clicks a download button. Previously, the downloading icon would appear in the bottom of the browser indicating that the file was saving. Now, that does not appear and the file does not save. The status code of the response is 200 OK, which makes debugging the problem difficult as according to Visual Studio, the response is executing fine.

Am I doing something wrong with HttpContext response that would disable it from functioning? Or is there some feature I need to enable for this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
byte[] byteArray = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringb.ToString());
response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
```

instead of:

```
response.Write(sb.ToString()); 
response.End();
```